# how to remove megamenu's items from significant keywords of SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords

I have a megamenu in my website which contains hundreds of items, a lot of the lists have numerous items which i had to add a "View all" link at the end of the list to redirect the visitor to the category. Something like this:

- Cat
- Dog
- Squirrel
- Parrot
- Some more items here
- Some more items here
- Some more items here
- View all animals>

Now the problem is, since i use this phrase quiet a lot, google and other seo tools have detected "view" and "all" as my most significant keyword, which is horribly wrong.

I can use image instead of "view all" containing this text, but it's not a good idea, let's face it; it's not a good idea.

This is just preventing my real keyword from showing up in any SEO checkers that i tried.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: *google and other seo tools*... it will be highly beneficial to know what you are looking at. For example, the Google Search Console content keywords list is pure junk if that is one. It is highly unlikely that search resources are being wasted with "view all" since no-one is searching for that at all. As well, there is no limit to what a site can rank for in numbers of terms. So I am sure, you have nothing to worry about. Especially in light of how many highly reputable sites do the same thing. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes one of my sources is the google search console. Buy other SEO tools such as woorank will reflect the same results. Also there is another awkward issue that i noticed today. Search console indicated that i have used 'view all' for over 3000 times in like 10 pages, which is not true, about 20 times at each page at max, but 3000...

Comment: Sassan, Google ignores content that is repeated. It is able to detect things in menus, footers and sidebar... Just because your app or webmaster tools is reporting those keywords does not mean they are being used in Google's Algorithm for actual ranking purposes. I recommend that you either ignore it or purchase an app that is clever enough to work out what is content and what is inot.

Comment: Just a detail. It helps if <aside>, <nav> and <footer> tags are used for 'repeat' items and <main> for the main content . I think if Sasan figures out the 3,000 times thing, the contents keyword list will become more indicative of the site's content. However... this perhaps needs asking as a separate question and not necessarily in this Stack but a programming one instead like StackOverflow.

Comment: @SimonHayter thank you. Is there any premium seo checker that you would recommend? The one i use does not have such feature.

Comment: I don't recommend any keyword based checker. Your content should be written for users and not search engines. Keyword Density and Relevance is simply not the same it was a decade ago. You used to have to worry about if you had too many keywords or not enough, now its all about writing natural content. Content that is written for search engines have a poor Flesch rating and impacts on user experience and in-direct SEO.

Comment: @SimonHayter well then to be short, quality for users matters, not perfect algorithm for search engines.thank you.